# share variable into multi include (php)

Tags: php, include, global-variables, share

i don't undestand why my variable is not set after multi include.

in header.php, i have a variable $a

```
public function defaultShow(){

        include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../view/app/header.php");
        include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../view/app/accueil.php");
        include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../view/app/footer.php");

}
```

in accueil.php $a is set. it's works

but if my code is

```
public function defaultShow(){

        self::includeView("app/header");        
        self::includeView("app/accueil");
        self::includeView("app/footer");

}

public static function includeView($view){      
        include dirname(__FILE__)."/../view/".$view.".php";
}
```

accueil.php is loaded but $a is empty in this file.

all variables set in header.php is empty in accueil.php

why ?

thanks for replies

Guillaume

Comment: global $a;
$a = 'max';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is a pitfall to avoid. In case you need to access your variable
>   $a within a function, you need to say "global $a;" at the
>   beginning of that function. You need to repeat this for each function
>   in the same file.

**Example:**

**will only show errors.**

```
include('front.php');
global $a;

function foo() {
  echo $a;
}

function bar() {
  echo $a;
}

foo();
bar();
```

**The correct way to do that would be:**

```
include('front.php');

function foo() {
  global $a;
  echo $a;
}

function bar() {
  global $a;
  echo $a;
}

foo();
bar();
```

Comment: Okkzzz .. Then Please Tick Mark As Correct  to The My Ans ... :)